# Determining user access in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

We would like to get a list of all jobs that a user has access to in Jenkins.  This would probably be via a System Groovy Script but I am open to other methods.

We want to be able to test that all security is setup correctly and as admins we see everything so a script like this would be helpful.

This would have the same functionally as the "My View" tab in views.

Scott

Comment: Is it not possible to create a dummy user that has the same permissions set as the non admins and log in as that?

Comment: We use AD that is synced with a Corporate user store so that would not be an option